# my python code is getting a (list index out of range error) ...can anyone get me a reason why

Tags: python-2.7

Given below is a python code supposed to read the values from a list and gets the sum of all the values after squaring each of them.

```
def squareEach(nums):
    for i in nums[:-1]:
        s=nums[i]*nums[i]
        nums[i]=s


def sums(num):
    sum1=1
    for i in num[:-1]:
        sum1=sum1+num[i]
    return sum1


def toNumbers(strlist):
    for i in range(len(strlist)):
        strlist[i]=int(strlist[i])

file=raw_input("enter a filename: ")
openf=open(file,'w')
openf.write("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10")
openf=open(file,'r')


s=''
for i in openf:
    s=i
s=string.split(s)

for i in range(len(s)):
    s[i]=int(i)
squareEach(s)
s=sums(s)
print s
```

This is the Program and I am getting an error. Why?

Answer (score 2):

Python for loops iterate over the elements (not the indices) of a list:

```
for i in [1, 2, 4]:
   print i

# Prints 1, 2 and 4
```

You'll have modify the existing one by working with the index of each element:

```
def squareEach(nums):
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        nums[i] = nums[i]*nums[i]
```

Although I would make a function that creates a new list instead:

```
def squareEach(nums):
    return [n**2 for n in nums]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous problems with your code. I'd recommend trying to read some more Python tutorials to make sure you understand the basics.

```
file=raw_input("enter a filename: ")
```

`file` is a builtin, and it's considered bad practice to redefine builtins. Standard convention is to put an underscore at the end of the name, for instance `file_`.

```
s=''
for i in openf:
    s=i
```

This will simply assign s to the last line of the file. What you may have intended is `s = openf.read()`, which will give you the entire file contents.

```
for i in range(len(s)):
    s[i]=int(i)
```

This assigns the contents of s to a bunch of integers, completely discarding whatever you read from the file. What you probably meant was `s = map(int, s)`. Note that the use of map is somewhat controversial, some people prefer list comprehensions even though the `map` version is shorter and easier in this case.

```
for i in nums[:-1]:
```

This iterates over everything except the last number in the list.

```
for i in nums[:-1]:
    s=nums[i]*nums[i]
    nums[i]=s
```

In addition to the aforementioned slice problem, you're iterating over the values in the list, not the indices. The most idiomatic way to write what you're trying to do is

```
nums[:] = [x*x for x in nums]
```

P.S. Please read the guidelines to posting questions on Stack Overflow.